# How to use READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm having a database which is used heavily. A lot of writing/reading is done simultanosly. Therefore I've decided to use snapshots to reduce/avoid deadlocks.

I'v turned on `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`, but do I need to specify what transaction level to use in each SP aswell?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set this on the database-level?  If so, then unless otherwise overridden in a query then no you don't need to specify `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` again.

Setting transaction Isolation Level:

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDb
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
```

I'm guessing you did the above?

Also, I hope you understand what exactly this Transaction Isolation Level entails.  It has to do with row versioning and is quite the hit on `tempdb`.  It's not always the answer to heavy "writing/reading".  Not to mention it utilizes row versioning, so you may not be getting what you think you should be getting.

Comment: Btw, do you know how long it should take to put it on?

Comment: @johan Put what on?

Comment: running the alter database script can only be done in single user mode. Otherwise the query never finnish

Answer (score 1):

Be careful: when we turn on READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT, we can break existing code. I wrote a few examples here: [When Snapshot Isolation Helps and When It Hurts](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/32957)